# Domain entities - automatic ids?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

Domain entities are always unique and therefore need an identifier that's unique accross the domain. A common approach is to decorate a domain entity with a id and leave it open to the underlying architectural technology to set that id.

```
public MyDomainEntity {  
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Mostly, domain entities get stored in a database that is capable of auto incrementing ids. Or we use a ORM mapper that allowes to generate ids (UUIDs etc.)

However, I find this approach very problematic. Who guarantees that the e.g. database is capable of generating an id? And who ensures that the automatic id fits the requirements of the domain?

If I want to specify how entities are being made unique and how new ids are being generated - where do I implement this? On the repository implementations? On UnitOfWorks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since an id is something technical, there should not be any requirements of the domain towards id generation.

If you want to control id generation, then I think the repository would be the best place to do it.

Comment: Is an id something technical? Let's say I'm a government and I issue plate numbers for drivers. The plate numbers need to be autogenerated (except a driver wishes for a certain number, but that's another story) and they are always unique, so they're technically an id, but a requirement of a domain.

Comment: just because something is unique, it isn't automatically an id. More importantly, to be an id, it needs to be an id of an entity.
Let's call it a contract between the government and the car owner that has an attribute called "licensePlateNumber". That is not automatically an id. The id would be the id of the contract, and the license plate number is just an attribute.

Comment: If you look at it that way, you're correct. But then again we have the problem that an licensePlateNumber should be unique. If something can be unique depends on the technical implementation. EntityFramework for instance doesn't allow "unique", so the only way to make an attribute unique is to look at it as it would be an key. So I would need to make my entity id the license plate number to guarantee that it stays unique among the table. I'll take your suggestion and handle it in the repository, that sounds like a reasonable advice.

Comment: my suggestion to put id generation in the repository was for a technical id. The way I see it is: An Id should be technical and therefor its creation in a technical component like the repository. But when you have a natural id that has a meaning in the domain world, then the id must be created in the domain layer. Afterall, there is domain logic necessary to create it.